# [help]ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list)

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

I am currently in a course for machine learning but I am getting stuck at this point. my code is also the exact same as the instructor shows but he keeps changing the code off-screen can anybody help

````
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import preprocessing
import numpy

imdb = keras.datasets.imdb
(train_data, train_lables), (test_data, test_lables) = imdb.load_data(num_words=10000)

_word_index = imdb.get_word_index()

word_index = {k:(v+3) for k,v in _word_index.items()}
word_index["<PAD>"] = 0
word_index["<START>"] = 1
word_index["<UNK>"]  = 2
word_index["<UNUSED>"] = 3

reverse_word_index = dict([(value, key) for (key, value) in word_index.items()])

def decode_review(text):
    return " ".join([reverse_word_index.get(i, "?") for i in text])

train_data=keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(train_data, value=word_index["<PAD>"], padding="post",maxlen=250)

train_data=keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(test_data, value=word_index["<PAD>"], padding="post",maxlen=250)

model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(88000, 16))
model.add(keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))

model.summary()

model.compile(optimizer="adam",loss="binary_crossentropy",metrics=["accuracy"])

x_val = train_data[:10000]
x_train = train_data[10000:]

y_val = train_lables[:10000]
y_train = train_lables[10000:]

fitModel = model.fit(x_train, y_train,epochs=40,batch_size=512,validation_data=(x_val, y_val),verbose=1)

results = model.evaluate(test_data, test_lables)
```
````

Comment: What is the error message? And in which line do you get the error? Please attach full error message.

Comment: Just based on the error message - at some point `numpy` probably tried to convert a list of lists into an array, but the lists weren't all the same length.  So instead of a 2-dimensional array of values, `numpy` made a 1-dimensional array of list objects.  `Tensorflow` didn't know what to do with this.  Where this happened would be more clear with the full error trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's here:

```
train_data = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(test_data, value=word_index["<PAD>"], padding="post",maxlen=250)
^^^^^^^^^^                                              ^^^^^^^^^
```

This should start with `test_data` instead.  Since `test_data` never gets padded, it ends up with different length lists, can't be converted to `ndarray` and then can't be converted to a tensor.

Comment: Isn't there any way to use embeddings without padding? If they are gonna be fed to an LSTM, for instance, the sequences don't need to be the same length, and the embeddings work word-wise so I can't see why padding is a must

Comment: answering myself: yes, there is a way. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/71385349/6878997